# Protect CXF Service in Fuse with Basic Authentication on LDAP Users

Tags: cxf, basic-authentication, jbossfuse

I have a SOAP/REST service implemented in CXF inside Red Hat JBoss Fuse (in a Fabric).
I need to protect it with Basic Authentication, and credentials must be checked on a LDAP server.

Can this be done without a custom interceptor?

Can I maybe use the container JAAS security (configured with LDAP) to protect the service the same way I can protect the console?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the container JAAS security realm can be used to protect a web service.
An example is [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts/tree/master/cxf/secure-rest).
The example page doesn't explain the implementation, but a quick look at the blueprint.xml file reveals the following configuration:

```
<jaxrs:server id="customerService" address="/securecrm">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="customerSvc"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref component-id="authenticationFilter"/>
    </jaxrs:providers> 
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.security.JAASAuthenticationFilter">
    <!-- Name of the JAAS Context -->
    <property name="contextName" value="karaf"/>
</bean>
```

So it's just a matter of configuring a JAAS authentication filter.
"karaf" is the default JAAS realm for the container: users are defined in etc/users.properties
To define more realms, info is [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Security_Guide/files/ESBSecureJAASRealmDef.html).
To have users on LDAP, see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Security_Guide/files/ESBSecurityLDAPAuthentPlugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but please note that for more recent versions of Fuse (past 6.1), the "rank" in the LDAP configuration must be greater than 100 in order to override the default karaf realm.

Also, with current patches applied, in Fuse 6.2.X, connection pooling for the LDAP connections can be enabled:

```
   <!-- LDAP connection pooling -->
   <!-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html -->
   <!-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html -->
   context.com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true

  </jaas:module>
</jaas:config>
```

This is very important for high volume web-services.  A connection pool is maintained to the LDAP server.  This both avoids connection creation overhead and having closing sockets lingering in TIME-WAIT state.

Comment: Very useful information. Can you please post a link to the docs explaining these details? Thank you.

Comment: For the connection pooling, please see: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2219901